# how can i animate opening and closing filter the best way ReactJS

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-animations, styled-components

[image]

I have an animation that works as I expect to, but the problem is I set the half-height of it statically. But as soon as the height of an element changes it won't be working the appropriate way. [Here is the link for Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/bold-hofstadter-uvjs0?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

```
const close = keyframes`
  0% {opacity: 1; height: auto;}
  50% {opacity: 0.4; height: 203px; 
  filter: blur(0.2rem);}
  100% {opacity: 0; 
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 0;}
`;

const open = keyframes`
  0% {opacity: 0; height: 0; overflow: hidden; filter: blur(0.3rem);}
  50% { height: 203px; filter: blur(0.0rem);}
  100% {opacity: 1; height: auto;}
`;

const StyledFilterContainer = styled.div`
   .filter-inner {
        background: #f8f9fd;
        padding: 30px 36px;
        border-radius: 24px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.04) inset;
    }
   opacity: 0; 
   overflow: hidden;
   height: 0;
    animation: ${({isActive, isFilterClicked}) =>
    isFilterClicked ?
        isActive
            ? css`
          ${open} 0.6s ease forwards
        `
            : css`
          ${close} 0.6s ease forwards
        `
        :
        ''
};

`


const FilterContainer = ({children, ...props}) => {
       return (
        <StyledFilterContainer {...props} isActive={!!props.className} isFilterClicked={props.isFilterClicked}>
            <div className={`filter-inner`}>
                {children}
            </div>
        </StyledFilterContainer>

    )
}



export default function App() {
      const onClickFilterToggle = () => {
        toggleFilter(!isFilterOpen);
        toggleFilterClicked(true)
      } 
      const [isFilterOpen, toggleFilter] = useState(false);
      const [isFilterClicked, toggleFilterClicked] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <FilterContainer className={isFilterOpen ? 'active': ''} isFilterClicked= 
         {isFilterClicked} id = 'filterContainer'>
          <div>AAA</div>
      </FilterContainer>
          <button variant="secondary" $iconOnly onClick={ onClickFilterToggle } 
             tooltip={isFilterOpen ? 'Close filter': 'Open 
             filter'}>Button
          </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

So, the question is here :

```
const open = keyframes`
   0% {opacity: 0; height: 0; overflow: hidden; filter: blur(0.3rem);}
   50% { height: 203px; filter: blur(0.0rem);}
   100% {opacity: 1; height: auto;}
`;
```

`height: 203px;` Needs to be replaced on something dynamic like `height: 50%;`, or maybe there is a better way to do a whole thing.

Comment: Please add the code to the question

Comment: @hellogoodnight ok, but its all in sanbox

Comment: That's the rules brother

Comment: @hellogoodnight added